# отрицательное слово "нет"

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Каким членом предложения является слово "нет" в примере"Нет, книга еще лежала на прилавке" (в смысле, ее не продали, чего так боялся автор)?

Answer (score 1):

1) О словах ***да*** и ***нет***

Розенталь рассматривает слова *да* и *нет* в следующей теме: § 29. Утвердительные, отрицательные и вопросительно-восклицательные слова http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=129#pp129

В разных источниках ***нет*** называют **частицей, модельной частицей, междометием.**

НЕТ, I. частица. 1. Употр. как отрицательный ответ на вопрос или как выражение несогласия (**может выступать в качестве предложения**; противоп.: да). Есть будешь? - Нет. Вы поедете на симпозиум? - Нет. Садитесь, пожалуйста. - Нет, нет, спасибо.

Если слово ***нет*** входит в состав предложения, то оно **обособляется, но членом предложения не является,** как и все вводные слова или междометия. В то же время ***нет*** может оформляться как **отдельное предложение.**

2) Ответ на вопрос

***Нет, книга еще лежала на прилавке.***

Этот вариант не так прост для анализа. Приведенное предложение является **неполным**, его состав восстанавливается по контексту: ***Нет, не продана,  книга еще лежала на прилавке.***

Поэтому слово ***нет*** фактически заменяет целое предложение, и в состав следующего предложения оно не входит.

Так что можно остановится на варианте **"может выступать в качестве предложения".**

Answer (score 0):

> Каким членом предложения является слово "нет"

Никаким не является.

Нет - это частица. Частицы не являются членами предложения (а исключением случаев, когда выступают в роли других частей речи), но могут входить в состав членов, образованных знаменательными словами.

В данном случае НЕТ - частица грамматически изолированная, выражает только  отрицание, в состав других членов предложения не входит.